# View contents of ehcache in GUI

Tags: debugging, ehcache, weblogic12c

Is there any application to view the ehCache of local weblogic server ? Like eclipse debugging mode, we can able to see the value of variable which are in scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at Ehcache monitoring documentation

- Through JMX : http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/operations/jmx.html#jmx-overview-
- Through Monitor : http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/operations/monitor